# How do I open the man page for square brackets math and what are they called?

Tags: bash

I have been working with them for a while now (math equations in `$[]`, not the arrays)

```
arrConflicts[0]=$[arrConflicts[0]+1]
currentCombination=$[ (arrFiles[0]-1+arrFiles[0]-i)*i/2-arrFiles[0]+j ]
```

1. How to call the man page?
2. What is this math called (to google)?
3. Does it have a min and max function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's one way of doing [arithmetic expansion in bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html#Arithmetic-Expansion). It was deprecated *years* ago, and current GNU documentation doesn't mention it (Ubuntu's manpages still do, though: run `man bash` and see the section on **Arithmetic Expansion**). From [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2415777/2072269):

> The manpage for bash v3.2.48 says:
>
> > [...] The format for arithmetic expansion is:
> >
> > ```
> >      $((expression))
> > ```
> >
> > The **old format $[expression] is deprecated** and will be removed in upcoming versions
> >     of bash.

You should use `$((...))` instead.

No, it doesn't have `min` or `max` functions.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea `$[]` was a thing.  I expected from the title that the answer was going to be `man '['`.  (i.e. `test`)

Comment: @PeterCordes :D thanks. you saved me! `man test` heh